# Strange behavior in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm reading a tutorial in http://www.nodebeginner.org and I have a strange behavior in data output. I know, there's a similar question on Stackoverflow but there's no answer. So I have this code of web-server:

```
//server.js
var http = require('http')
var url = require('url')

function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var postData = ""
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname
        console.log("Request for " + pathname + " recieved.")

        request.setEncoding('utf8')
        request.addListener("data", function(postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk
            console.log("Recieved POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk +"'.")
        })

        request.addListener("end", function() {
            route(handle, pathname, response, postData)
        })
        var content = route(handle, pathname, response)
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(80, '192.168.1.34')
    console.log("Server has started")
}

exports.start = start
```

Code of router.js which calls requestHandler.upload - my buggy function

```
//router.js
function route(handle, pathname, response, postData) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname)
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](response, postData) //calls requestHandler.upload 
    } else {
        console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname)
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'})
        response.write("404 Not found")
        response.end()
    }
}
```

And the code of requestHandler.upload

```
//requestHandler.js
function upload(response, postData) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called with POST data: " + postData); //works fine
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("You've sent: " + postData); //works ugly
    response.end();
}
```

Let's assume that in POST data there is a string `text=123`. The first line of this function outputs real data like `"Request handler 'upload' was called with POST data: text=123"`. Although, this line `response.write("You've sent: " + postData);` outputs in browser next message: `You've sent: undefined`. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code in `server.js` the line:

```
var content = route(handle, pathname, response)
```

Is being run first before the call in the `"end"` event listener, executing the function but omitting the `postData` argument. It runs...

```
response.write("You've sent: " + postData);
response.end();
```

Therefore, the response sent back to the browser is:

```
You've sent: undefined
```

The `"end"` event is being triggered afterwards and the event listener calls...

```
route(handle, pathname, response, postData)
```

Which correctly passes the `postData` and this gets correctly output to the console. The call to `response.write(...)` is not posted back to the browser the second time because the response at this point has ended.

I hope that explains the problem.

**EDIT** The answer is to remove the call

```
var content = route(handle, pathname, response)
```

The `"end"` event will then be called when the client has finished posting data and you are correctly running the `route` function at that point.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was my own awful mistake.